# Bash commands run in sequence

Tags: bash, unix, command-line

The problem:

Number of the commands must be executed consequently, written in one-line command:

```
comamand1; command2; command3;
```

The very first command is

```
 sw user_name;
```

The problem is that no commands are executed after the **sw user_name;** one. (the user gets changed though)

Any ideas about how i can execute the string of the commands described above?
[image]

P.S.

```
bash-3.2$ sw
Sorry, user ehwe is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -' as root on server_name
```

Guess it explains what the sw is :)

P.P.S
**sw** stands for **/bin/su -**

Comment: `sw`? What's this command supposed to do? Aren't you trying to use `su`?

Comment: tbh i dont know why, but it changes the user (see the update)

Comment: `sw` almost certainly starts a new interactive shell, so the next command in the sequence would not run until that shell exits.

Comment: may be sw is an alias or softlink to su. what does "ls -l `which su`"  output say?

Comment: Sorry, didnt quite get what needs to be typed into bash from your last comment

Comment: execute this command `which sw` and please share the output

Comment: bash-3.2$ which sw -->
/usr/bin/sw

Answer (score 5):

Hoping that you meant "su" and not "sw" . If you wanted to switch as some user and execute set of commands probably you can use -c option. you can try something like this `su - chidori -c "date;ls;df"`

Comment: bash-3.2$ sw upstream_mdm -c "date;ls;" -->
Sorry, user ehwe is not allowed to execute '/bin/su - upstream_mdm -c date;ls;' as root on server_name

Comment: guess it is a permissions issue -_-

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like `sw` might be some sort of alias to `su`. You can check with `alias sw`. If this is the case, you could probably use chidori's answer, just replace `su` with `sw`.

Comment: bash: alias: sw: not found

Comment: If you try `which sw`, then `ls -l` that file?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the user of a given process; you can only start a new process running as the new user. As such, `sw` is probably starting a new interactive shell. When that shell exits, the `sw` command completes, and the next command in your sequence can complete. For example:

```
$ sw user_name; echo "Second command executes"
$ echo hello
hello
$ exit
Second command executes
```

Comment: is there a way to run this echo command under the user_name user ?

Comment: See @chidori's answer, if `sw` is anything like `su`.